# onelogin php-saml userdata not found

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I am using one-login's php-saml library to use as an SP to connect to a client's IDP. For some reason though, when the client sends their SAML response, the array that is set by

```
$_SESSION['samlUserdata'] = $auth->getAttributes()
```

returns empty. If anyone has any insight as to what reason(s) why this could be happening, it would be greatly appreciated if you would share.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend to check your own saml metadata.

Do you have a list of attributes you want to get? Like:

```
    <md:AttributeConsumingService index="1">
        <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">Service</md:ServiceName>
        <md:ServiceDescription xml:lang="en">Sign-on</md:ServiceDescription>
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="username" isRequired="true" />
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="email" isRequired="true" />
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="firstName" isRequired="true" />
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="lastName" isRequired="true" />
    </md:AttributeConsumingService>
```

Second, if applicable, try to capture an incoming request and analyze it manually.

Also, ensure the client is properly configured according to your metadata.

It won't send everything about a logged in user.

The client has to explicitly declare/map/configure attributes for your SAML.